# Clojure filter method without standard clojure functions

Tags: clojure

I need to make `filter` method, but i can't return method name as argument, not as result.

In my case, i need to input odd? method as argument and call recursion.

I can use only this construction:

```
(defn my-filter [p xn])
```

My code:

```
(defn my-filter [p xs]
  (if (p (first xs))
      (cons (first xs) (recur p (next xs))) 
      (recur p (next xs) )))


(my-filter odd? '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

Error: IllegalArgumentException Argument must be an integer:   clojure.core/even? (core.clj:1372)

As i can see, where recursion is called, arguments are calculating result, instead of call recursion with odd? and (next xs) arguments

Comment: (The indentation is misleading - the second recurring "my-filter" is the "else" part of the "if".)

Answer (score 3):

Two issues need attention. Or maybe only one issue, if you don't need to handle very long lists.  1) The function does not notice when the inputs are exhausted. Open a REPL and try `(odd? nil)` and you will see what happens!  2) If you try the function on a really long list, you might get a StackOverflow.  The clojure.org guide for recursion has an example of how to avoid that problem - actually it illustrates solutions to both problems:  https://clojure.org/guides/learn/flow#_recursion

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not compile:

```
Syntax error (UnsupportedOperationException) compiling recur at ... .
Can only recur from tail position
```

You have to replace the `recur`s with explicit recursive calls to `my-filter`:

```
(defn my-filter [p xs]
  (if (p (first xs))
    (cons (first xs) (my-filter p (next xs)))
    (my-filter p (next xs))))
```

Now it compiles, but ...

```
(my-filter odd? [])
Execution error (IllegalArgumentException) at ...
Argument must be an integer:
```

You need to check that the sequence argument `xs` is not empty before doing anything else with it:

```
(defn my-filter [p xs]
  (when (seq xs)
    (if (p (first xs))
      (cons (first xs) (my-filter p (rest xs)))
      (my-filter p (rest xs)))))
```

The `when` evaluates to `nil` if the condition fails. The `nil`, called on to be a sequence, behaves as an empty one. So ...

```
(my-filter odd? [])
=> nil
(my-filter odd? (range 10))
=> (1 3 5 7 9)
```

It works. However, it evaluates `(first xs)` twice, and mentions `(my-filter p (rest xs))` twice. Factoring these out, we get

```
(defn my-filter [p xs]
  (when (seq xs)
    (let [head (first xs)
          tail (my-filter p (rest xs))]
      (if (p head) (cons head tail) tail))))
```

This uses direct recursion. So it runs out of stack on a long sequence:

```
(count (my-filter odd? (range 10000)))
Execution error (StackOverflowError) at ...
```

Wrapping the recursion in `lazy-seq` flattens the evaluation, devolving it to whatever explores the sequence:

```
(defn my-filter [p xs]
  (lazy-seq
    (when (seq xs)
      (let [head (first xs)
            tail (my-filter p (rest xs))]
        (if (p head) (cons head tail) tail)))))
```

Now ...

```
(count (my-filter odd? (range 10000)))
=> 5000
```

If you want an eager version, you had better build the returned sequence as a vector:

```
(defn eager-filter [p coll]
  (loop [answer [], coll (seq coll)]
    (if-let [[x & xs] coll]
      (recur
        (if (p x) (conj answer x) answer)
        xs)
      (sequence answer))))
```

This won't run out of stack:

```
(count (eager-filter odd? (range 10000)))
=> 5000
```

But it can't handle an endless sequence:

```
(first (eager-filter odd? (range)))

Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)
```

I had to kill the process.

Answer (score 0):

I really like this solution, therefore I share with you. Very simple. (I know, that is not exactly what was the question but different approach.)

```
(def data (vec (range 10)))
```

Map implementation

```
(defn -map [f coll]
  (reduce
    (fn [acc v]
      (conj acc (f v)))
    []
    coll))
```

Filter implementation

```
(defn -filter [f coll]
  (reduce
    (fn [acc v]
      (if (f v)
        (conj acc v))
    []
    coll))
```

Example usage

```
(->> data
     (-map inc)
     (-filter odd?))
```